# How to var_dump SilverStripe variables in templates

Tags: debugging, silverstripe

I started using SilverStripe php CMS/Framework. Is there any way we can `var_dump` a variable in the .ss templates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Debug::dump($theDataYouWantToDump)` to dump any data in the browser or command line anywhere in your php Silverstripe codebase. Also, you can run `.debug` off of any DataObject, ViewableData object in the `.ss` template to view the underlying data.

Example, you can do this in your Silverstripe `PageController` class to dump out test data.

```
public function init(){
    parent::init();
    Debug::dump("dumping test data from the controller init function");
}
```

Or you can do some thing like this in your `.ss` template to dump out test data.

```
 $Page('home').debug
```

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in SilverStripe's templates are pulled in via the controller. You should be able to `var_dump` the variable from the controller using PHP.

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#variables

Answer (score 0):

Put either of these in your PHP code, most often in your Controller, where $myVariable is either a custom function or simply a variable to test what data is coming back. It should show up at the very top of your web page when you reload it...

```
Debug::show($myVariable); // formated output
// vs
print_r($myVariable); // unformated output
```

I can't recall if there's an actual .ss template variable that does anything like this other than creating a custom function and calling it like a normal template variable, which is no different then the above two options.